# I cant increase clickpower variable on my game

Tags: python, pgzero

So i tried to make an clickpower variable on my game.

I tried making these:

```
clickpower = 1
```

And the part where you buy an upgrade and increase your clickpower by 1.

```
if upgbutton.collidepoint(pos):
            if puan >= 10:
                upgbutton.pos = (744,80)
                animate(upgbutton, tween= "bounce_end", duration = 1, x = 744, y = 100)
                clickpower + 1
                puan - 10
            else:
                upgbutton.pos = (734,80)
                animate(upgbutton, tween= "accel_decel", duration = 0.3, x = 744, y = 100)
```

Also these codes except click power is in

```
def on_mouse_down(button,pos):
    global puan, clickpower
    if button == mouse.LEFT:
```

I tried increasing the clickpower in a condition. Making the upgrade button have a condition to press, and that is having 10+ points(or exactly 10)

But when i click the upgrade button with the having 10+ points, it doesnt increase my clickpower. can someone fix or change the code i wrote?

Comment: please see how to properly format code blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `clickpower = clickpower + 1`

Comment: or `clickpower += 1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to Clickpower +=1. Clickpower + 1 doesn't mean anything in Python. You have to change the variable value with an equals sign.